# Save entity without validation

Tags: 8, forms

While adding a new submit button to the form

```
$form['actions']['save_as_draft'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Save as Draft'),
  '#submit' => ['::submitForm', '::save', 'save_as_draft'],
  '#validate' => [],
  '#limit_validation_errors' => []
];
$form['#validate'] = [['validate_errors']];
```

This does not save the entity. I am not sure how to edit the following validate function.

```
function validate_errors(&$form,FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  if ($form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#value'] == t('Save as Draft')) {
    // Skip validation.
  }else {
    // Validate here.
  }
}
```

Meanwhile, I got the error when saving (Entity validation was skipped):
[image]

Any inputs on how I can fix this and allow the entity to be saved without validation?

Comment: Have you ever figured out how to save the entity? I tried using `$entity = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()` and then  `$entity->save();` in my custom submit handler but in vain.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Instead of "#limit_validation_error", adding validation handler which simply omits all the error works fine.

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['actions']['save_as_draft'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save as Draft'),
    '#submit' => ['::submitForm', '::save',],
    '#validate' => ['_my_module_clear_errors'],
  ];

  // Add this to avoid 'Entity validation was skipped' error.
  $form_state->setTemporaryValue('entity_validated', TRUE);
}

// Remove all errors.
function _my_module_clear_errors(&$form,FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->clearErrors();
}
```

This comment was really helpful

https://www.drupal.org/project/workflow/issues/2859053#comment-12140370